# How to update column values in all lines in a text file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, powershell-4.0

I have a text file that has 1000's of lines. And each lines has elements that are separated by tilde(~) delimiter. Now, i want to just change the first column value numbers to a Random/Unique number, i.e 34324242342333. It is of 15 chars length. But this is not working.

```
34324242342333~22~BB74~001~ 
34656453535353~22~C23~001~ 
00900900900889~22~N99~001~ 
97002021207021~22~F22~001~ 
23423432423421~22~V99~001~
```

**Powershell code:**

```
 $FileContent = Get-Content -Path C:\TestFiles\DummyData1.txt
        foreach ($Row in $FileContent) {
         $RandomNumber= Get-Random -Minimum 111111111111111 -Maximum 999999999999999
         $fields =  $Row.Split("~")
         $fields[0] =  $RandomNumber
         $fields -join '~' 
        }  Set-Content | C:\TestFiles\DummyDataUpdated.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PowerShell doesn't permit piping the output of a `foreach` statement directly. To make your existing code working with the least amount of changes, wrap the `foreach` statement in a scriptblock:

```bash
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path C:\TestFiles\DummyData1.txt

# Wrap foreach in a scriptblock to be able to pipe it to Set-Content
& {
    foreach ($Row in $FileContent) {
         $RandomNumber= Get-Random -Minimum 111111111111111 -Maximum 999999999999999
         $fields =  $Row.Split("~")
         $fields[0] =  $RandomNumber
         $fields -join '~' 
    }  
} | Set-Content C:\TestFiles\DummyDataUpdated.txt
```

Here `& {…}` defines a scriptblock and immediately executes it, using the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#call-operator-).

Also I've fixed the typo in the `Set-Content` call (there should be no pipe symbol before the file path argument).

---

As an alternative, streamlined solution, get rid of the temporary variable `$fileContent` and use a single pipeline to avoid the `foreach` statement:

```bash
Get-Content -Path C:\TestFiles\DummyData1.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $RandomNumber= Get-Random -Minimum 111111111111111 -Maximum 999999999999999
    $fields =  $_.Split("~")
    $fields[0] =  $RandomNumber
    $fields -join '~' 
} | Set-Content C:\TestFiles\DummyDataUpdated.txt
```

The variable `$row` has been replaced by [automatic variable `$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#_) which denotes the current element processed by the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\sourceFile.txt -Delimiter '~' -Header @("colA","colB","colC","colD")
$csv | select @{N="colA";E={(Get-Random -Minimum 111111111111111 -Maximum 999999999999999)}},colB,colC,colD
```

Change the columns name to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [replacement with a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-with-a-script-block) on any digit which is not proceeded by anything but a digit:

```
Get-Content .\Data1.txt -Replace '(?<!\D.*)\d', { Random 9 } |Set-Content .\Updated.txt
```